# nested for in batch

Tags: windows, batch

I can't figure out where is the problem.
I have `tool.exe` which is used to grep, read and write registry.

It has `errorlevel` codes `0`, `1` and `2`, everything according syntax of this tool is correct:

> ```bat
> "%tool_ROOT%\BIN\tool.exe" /g "%%A" %%B "%%C"`
> ```

And works fine unless I wrap code into ***`for do (cmd)`***
Example:

```bat
::   %%A   // is registry path 
::   %%B   // is parameter 
::   %%C   // is value*

@echo off

set logfile=log.LOG

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=+" %%A in (CHECK.txt) do (
    "%tool_ROOT%\BIN\tool.exe" /g "%%A" %%B "%%C" 
    @if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (
        @ECHO %DATE% %TIME% ----- %%B WITH PARAMETER %%C ALREADY EXIST>>%logfile%
       )
    @if "%errorlevel%" == "1" ( 
        @ECHO %DATE% %TIME% -----CURRENT VALUE OF %%B is>>%logfile%
       )
    @if "%errorlevel%" == "2" (
        @ECHO %DATE% %TIME% -----%%B DOESN'T EXIST IN REGISTRY>>%logfile%
       )
    )
```

Already tried to put **`^`** before every closing **`)`**

Comment: Remove `@echo off` and share the output.

Comment: What is the content of check.txt? What is the screen output when you remove the @echo off and the @ before the IF and ECHO commands? As it stands we don't have enough information to give an answer. You can EDIT your question to add the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal

set "logfile=.\log.log"
set "tool_cmd=.\bin\tool.exe"

cd /d "Path\To\Tool\Exec\Root\Folder"

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=+" %%a in ('type "File_Check.txt" ^| find "+" 
')do (call ) & "%tool_cmd%" /g "%%~a" %%~b "%%~c" & >>"%logfile%" (
     if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (echo\ %date% %time% ----- %%b with parameter %%c already exist 
        )else if "%errorlevel%" == "1" (echo\ %date% %time% ----- current value of %%~b is
        )else if "%errorlevel%" == "2" (echo\ %date% %time% ----- %%~b doesn't exist in registry
        ) ) 
    
timeout -1 | type "%logfile% & endlocal
```

---

**1.** When defining your variables, make use of double quotes, just in case, or as a friend says, be at peace with yourself and use them...

```bat
set "logfile=log.log"
```

---

**2.** Set the full path to the executable, I didn't see it defined in your code, and also set the full path to your log file too...

```bat
set "logfile=D:\Path\To\log.log"
set "tool_cmd=D:\Path\To\Root\Tool\Folder\bin\tool.exe"
```

---

**3.** Submit you file to the `type` command, and use a `find` to filter just the lines with their `+` delimiter...

```bat
for ...('type "File_Check.txt" ^| find "+" ')do ...
```

---

**4.** As everything points to some problem/behavior related to the `errorlevel` value, before executing your command using your `...\tool.exe`, **[reset the `errorlevel` to `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113727/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-reset-errorlevel-to-zero)**, for test and see the results, of course you can remove after...

```bat
...)do (call ) & "%tool_cmd%" /g "%%~a" %%~b "%%~c"...
```

- **Obs.: 1** Be aware that there is a space in the command and it is necessary: ***`(callspace)`***
- **Obs.: 2** One `if` a previous another `if` executes the `echo string`, but if doesn't actually write to the log file, what will be the `errorlevel` value in this return? Does `errorlevel` value change after performing an `echo string + redirector to file`or not? These are prone to peculiarities that I strong suggest to testing and read the answer linked in the text below for better understanding...

> *[`Also note - This answer does not attempt to document the ERRORLEVEL result when an internal command encounters an error (except for a wee bit concerning DEL and ERASE)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/which-cmd-exe-internal-commands-clear-the-errorlevel-to-0-upon-success/34968021#34968021)*
>
> *[`Not only are there difference between commands, but a single command can behave differently depending on whether it was run from the command line, or within a batch script with a .bat extension, or from within a batch script with a .cmd extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/which-cmd-exe-internal-commands-clear-the-errorlevel-to-0-upon-success/34968021#34968021)* - **[`@dbenham`](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham)**

---

**5.** Use `if condition() else if condition()...` and not an `if condition()` on each isolated line, for a new condition treatment on the next line even when it has already met the defined condition in one or more previous line..

```bat
     if "%errorlevel%" == "0" (
          echo\ %date% %time% ----- %%b with parameter %%c already exist 
        ) else if "%errorlevel%" == "1" (
          echo\ %date% %time% ----- current value of %%~b is
        ) else if "%errorlevel%" == "2" (
          echo\ %date% %time% ----- %%~b doesn't exist in registry
        ) else (
          echo\ Look at this bro! 
          echo\ No previous one condition met as true! 
          echo\ What to do now?
          echo\ But if it is not necessary/does not occur, 
          echo\ you can remove the last else
          echo\ As i did in the answer code
        )
```

---

**6.** As for the redirection to your log file, I suggest executing the `if` command inside a block [`>file-log (if ())`], and already redirecting a single time whatever the `if condition` or any `else if condition()` that returns to same file...

```bat
"%tool_cmd%" /g "%%~a" %%~b "%%~c" & >>"%logfile%" ( 
    if.. else if.. else if...
   )
```

---

---

**obs.:** Note that without seeing the content (string layout) of your file, what I propose comes from assumptions....

---

Comment: Great answer @iTwasnTme.  I would also add that I personally find when the block gets too complicated the batch function style of  `call :label PARAMS` with `:label .... goto :EOF` makes the code easier to read (much like any other language).  It also doesn't require `enabledelayedexpansion` with the odd `!variable!` syntax.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas mi señor, gracias!,,, see, this answer (don't tell the author), tries to fish the layout of the text file for a future edition.... got it?